# Using ORDERBY in Where condition in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Select P.SecondName__c,P.FirstName__c, P.TransDate__c,  From PurchaseDE P
Where P.PubNbr__c = (Select distinct P.PubNbr__c from PurchaseDE P                                        
ORDERBY P.TransDate__c LIMIT1
 )
```

While using the above SQL query i am getting the error,OrderBy not supported in sub query.
The idea is to pull the publication No ( P.PubNbr__c) based on the transaction date (P.TransDate__c), the last transaction date will be picked for every publication No  P.PubNbr__c). How to achieve the above functionality. Any suggestions?

Comment: ORDERBY <> ORDER BY

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: Also LIMIT1 <> LIMIT 1

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, I assume that you want to select in `PurchaseDE` the record in last transaction date for every `PubNbr__c`

If that's the case, you could use:

```
Select 
    P.PubNbr__c, P.SecondName__c,P.FirstName__c, P.TransDate__c
From 
    PurchaseDE P
inner join
    (select 
        PubNbr__c, max(TransDate__c) last_TransDate 
    from
        PurchaseDE 
    group by
        PubNbr__c
    ) as lp
on
    lp.PubNbr__c = P.PubNbr__c
    and P.TransDate__c = lp.last_TransDate;
```

And if you only need Publication No and last transaction date then just use

```
select 
    PubNbr__c, max(TransDate__c) last_TransDate 
from
    PurchaseDE 
group by
    PubNbr__c;
```

Comment: Can you go through my query once again in the post there is only one table not two. I used your query but its not working

Comment: @AjitMishra If so then you should just change the table name to `PurchaseDE` like in my editted according to your updated question

Comment: Can you go through my query once again in the post there is only one table not two. I used your query but its not working. There is only one table PurchaseDE , from which i want to pick up the Publication no with the latest transaction date.This activity has to be done for every publication no. Ex: Publication No is 0001, it will have numerous of entries, i want to pick one record for 0001 with last transaction date. This has to be done for other transaction as well like 0002, 0003 etc as well

Comment: @AjitMishra Then my updated answer should work for you.

Comment: @RaviSankarRaju Who do you talking to, lad? Please stop blaming and try helping with a better solution. And for my answer, you could see [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a5bf/2) for tested result.